# What is the technical term for command line application environment programs?

Tags: command-line, terminology

Some programs that are run in the terminal, after calling them, switch the command line to their own environment, like "R" (statistical program language)  or "GHCi" (interactive Haskell).

What is the technical term for this?

References, tutorials how to write bash programs with their own environment would be great.

example

```
name@name ~$GOOFY
GOOFY >mv foo (where goofy's mv does something else then regular mv)
```

Answer (score 7):

I think [REPL (read-eval-print-loop)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) is what you are looking for.

From the wikipedia page:

> A read–eval–print loop (REPL), also known as an interactive toplevel or language shell, is a simple, interactive computer programming environment that takes single user inputs (i.e. single expressions), evaluates them, and returns the result to the user; a program written in a REPL environment is executed piecewise.

Comment: thanks, so this would mean that I can write a code that reads the input, make a calculation (or whatever) and instead of quitting, it just simply returns to an input line again. It makes sense, I though this was much more complicated.